# Serving additional directory content under root in Nginx

Tags: nginx, directory, root, alias

Using Nginx with Django, I have the following location entry in my server config:

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:1234;
}
```

Thus, all root URL requests are passed to Django.

Now, I'd like to serve some additional files, such as `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, and an indefinite number of other files, under the root URL as well. For example `/robots.txt` should return my `robots.txt` file, which lives in `/var/www/project/misc/`. How do I do this in Nginx? I can't seem to have several locations for capturing the root URL "/".

I know, I can do it like this:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/project/misc/robots.txt;
}
```

However, we're talking about a lot of different files, and adding an extra location for all of them seems to be rather clumsy. It would be better if there was a way for simply serving a whole directory under the root URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break out application into it's own @special location, then try the filesystem first.

```
location / {
    root /var/www/project/misc;
    try_files $uri @wsgiapp;
}

location @wsgiapp {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:1234;
}
```